how to focus on instagram post comment textarea using vanilla JS?
I can select the textarea using the devtools console but I cannot focus on it and start typing and because of that the post button is disabled.

BTW, I can do it using python + selenium.

Just a question, instead of typing in the textarea why don't you set the value of textarea?

Ah, I was testing it and found out that even setting the value in JavaScript won't make the Post button enabled.
